# Prove an integral inequality $|\int\limits_0^1f(x)dx|\leq\frac{1-a+b}{4}M$

Tags: integration, integral-inequality

Let $f$ be a differentiable function on $[0,1]$ and $a,b\in(0,1)$ such that $a<b$, $\int\limits_0^af(x)dx=\int\limits_b^1f(x)dx=0$. Show that: $$\left|\int_0^{1} f(x)\,dx\,\right|\leq\frac{1-a+b}{4}\,M$$ where $M=\sup\limits_{x\in[0,1]}|f'(x)|$.

Comment: What are your ideas on this problem?

Comment: So in fact you're assuming as well the derivative is bounded on the unit interval?

Comment: @ Matthias - you're missing the condition on the integrals between $0$ and $a$, and $b$ and $1$.

Comment: @ Matthias $\int_0^a x \mathrm{d}x \neq 0$ for $a > 0$.

Comment: Upps I missed the last equality. Thx.

Answer (score 8):

Since $f$ is continuous, it must have zeroes in both intervals $[0,a]$ and $[b,1]$. By the [Mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), we deduce that
$$
|f(a)| \leq Ma,\qquad |f(b)| \leq M(1-b).
$$

By the [Mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) again, there exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that
$$\frac{1}{b-a}\left[\int_a^bf(x)dx - \frac{1}{2}(b-a) [f(a)+f(b)]\right] = -(c-\frac{a+b}{2})f'(c).
$$
Therefore,
$$
\left|\int_a^b f(x)dx\right| \leq \frac{b-a}{2} \left(|f(a)| + |f(b)| + (b-a)M\right) \leq \frac{b-a}{2}M.
$$
The conclusion follows since $b-a < 1$ implies $\frac{b-a}{2} < \frac{b-a + 1}{4}$ and
$$
\int_0^1 f(x)dx = \int_a^b f(x)dx.
$$

Comment: It may help to note that in the second step he applied the mean value theorem to the function $g(x)=(\frac{a+b}{2}-x)f(x)+\int_0^x f(t) dt$.